# dialogresult does not work or partially work for some reason

Tags: c#

I made a form to be a dialog and the form only has one textbox, one OK button and one Cancel button. somehow, when the following does not work unless i change rnmForm.DialogResult!=DialogResult.OK), why is that????

```
 frmRename rnmForm = new frmRename();

        rnmForm.ShowDialog(new Form());
        if (rnmForm.DialogResult==DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make sure to set the dialog result to OK, before you close the dialog in the Ok click event?

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
this.Close();
```

Or setting the property on the Ok button, similar to this:

```
 btnOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

I also have to ask why you are calling showDialog and specifying a new instance of your form to be the owner, instead of just calling it with no parameters.  Just not sure that was intentional.

```
rnmForm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: umm i do have a click event on OK button, i have some simple string assignment ( assign textbox.TEXT to a string varable), what else should i do there?

Comment: edited.  Add this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Ok just before you call close.

Comment: actually, you are correct, i did new form without any intention, also, i put btnOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK after initialize then it worked                   public frmRename()
        {
           
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent; 
            InitializeComponent();
            btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }